# Swapping content in Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to create a Login/Register dialog using Angular Material. The dialog should switch between a login page and a register page when you click the 'Switch' button.

Here is the dialog html

```html
<md-dialog>
  <md-dialog-content>
    <div ng-if="lc.show_form == 'login'">
      <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && lc.login()" novalidate>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" required ng-model="project.email">

          <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error" ng-if="loginForm.email.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" required ng-model="project.password">

          <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-if="loginForm.password.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-button ng-click="lc.login()" class="md-raised md-primary">Login</md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="lc.showRegister()">Switch</md-button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="lc.show_form == 'register'">
      <form name="registerForm" ng-submit="registerForm.$valid && lc.register()" novalidate>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" required ng-model="project.email">

          <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error" ng-if="loginForm.email.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" required ng-model="project.password">

          <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-if="loginForm.password.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Password Confirm</label>
          <input type="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" required ng-model="project.password_confirm">

          <div ng-messages="loginForm.password_confirm.$error" ng-if="loginForm.password_confirm.$dirty">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-button ng-click="lc.register()" class="md-raised md-primary">Register</md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="lc.showLogin()">Switch</md-button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

here is the controller code

```js
angular.module('dialogDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($mdDialog, $log) {
    
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'dialogCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'lc',
                templateUrl: 'loginDialog.tmpl.html'
            });
       
  })
  .controller('dialogCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
    var self = this;
    self.show_form = 'login';
    
    self.showRegister = function() {
      self.show_form = 'register';
      console.log('show register');
    };

    self.showLogin = function() {
      self.show_form = 'login';
      console.log('show login');
    };
  });
```

Here is a plunker of what I am trying to accomplish.
http://plnkr.co/edit/nLeJHZB9XiIiiR9fPNEe?p=preview

Click the switch button. You will notice that the content changes, but if you click the switch button a second time the dialog only resizes, If you click it a third time it switches back. I am trying to figure out why it won't switch between the two views with only one click of the button.

Comment: the ng-message are not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plunker is working well for me.

I press `login` and i get the login modal, then i press `register` and the modal turns into register modal. If i press `login` again i get login modal.

pd: I am using chrome.

Comment: I was also using chrome, but now that I look at it again it is working. I must have had something cached in my browser.